# Cómo cambiar el color de las ocurrencias en Apache Netbeans 12?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría decir donde configurar para que no se vea de ese color?

Ya estuve buscando en las opciones pero no logro encontrar el apartado exacto en donde debería de modificar el resaltado de las ocurrencias.

Comment: Recuerda que SO en español es una comunidad de desarrolladores, mas no de personalización de IDES.

Comment: No veo que tu pregunta esté mal formulada ni fuera de lugar, está relacionada a desarrollo, y puede ser tranquilamente respondida por desarrolladores. Si bien S.O. es una comunidad de desarrolladores no quiere decir que la personalización de los IDE´s sea ajeno a ellos y que no ayude a las actividades de los mismos. Te dejo una respuesta que puede servirte.

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido a S.O. en Español. Te recomiendo que te des un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. También te recomiendo que vayas a [ask] para mejorar esta y/o las posibles preguntas que tengas en el futuro. Recuerda que mientras mejor redactada esté tu pregunta, será mas fácil de entender y por ende ayudará a obtener una respuesta mas rápido. Así mismo servirá a otras personas que también pudieran tener la misma duda. Que te vaya muy bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Mazitto, sigue estos pasos para conseguir lo que necesitas:

```
> 1. Herramientas-> Opciones-> Fuentes y colores
> 2. Sintaxis
> 3. Seleccionar idioma "Java"
> 4. Cambiar el fondo "Marcar las ocurrencias"
```